# Price taker vs price maker , in imperfect and perfect competition , alevel economics

Tags: microeconomics

This maybe like 3 questions in 1,could someone read it and make corrections?

I understand that when there are a large number of firms in the market this will mean that any decrease in price will lead to them gaining lot of customers but then losing them short after as everyone decreases their price , so they now end up with a lower quantity and less demand,.However we cannot show this on a perfect competition diagram and is the reason being because firms know this will happen it is not even an option for them to change their price this is why it is elastic  ?So the only time a firm undertakes price competition/change prices + and we can see the visible effects of this on the diagram is when there are more firms coming into the market or less firms coming into the market then we can see the price changes accompanied with the demand changes.

However for something like an oligopoly and the kinked demand curve we assume that the top section of the AR curve is elastic and the other half is inelastic , reason being if they increased their prices then they would lose a lot of customers for the same reason as price competition (but not lose all of them because of loyalty and product differentiation) ,if a firm decreases their price then they will not gain as much customers due to the same reasons as a perfect comp ,except that there is a minimal gain since they have some product differentiation. However what confused me is that if i said that a firm decreases their price in the elastic part of the diagram then will they gain a lot of customers (and i assumed this was due to price transparency and imperfect info ,so if they decreased the price then they would gain qd as firms havent reacted yet ), but this completely contradicts the argument of why i said the top part was elastic before, as i said if a firm increases their prices they will a lose a lot more qd  due to other firms not changing price which suggests that there is price transparency as thats why they lost a lot more qd .So the only conclusion i could up is that whenever there is a price decrease we just call the AR inelastic and when there is a price increase we call it elastic.